# i want to display my modal window on right side instead of popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrapping

There is a window which gets popped up on clicking a button and we used bootstrap modal for that . Instead of that window getting popped up I want it to get displayed in the same page right(the page in which i clicked the button). How to do that please help

Comment: Don't use a bootstrap modal, use a div and show/hide it based on the button click.

Comment: Can you provide a sample example how to use that div show/hide

Comment: Just get rid of the modal class container around the code you want, then position it accordingly on the screen. See here for more information http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp